# Bug? Checked new items remain unread in 'responses' tab

Tags: bug, profile-page, notifications

For instance, when I receive a comment I see the red indicator on the navigation bar. I click there, I click on the new message, I even respond. But when I navigate to my page, even after a day, I still see that the 'responses' tab has a blue indicator, showing there is a new item. But actually there is nothing new; Same item that I just checked.

This is quite annoying and I could not convince myself that it would be useful in any way.